# Scrapy xpath returns an empty list although tag and syntax are correct

Tags: xpath, scrapy

In my parse function, here is the code I have written:

```
hs = Selector(response)
links = hs.xpath(".//*[@id='requisitionListInterface.listRequisition']")
items = []
for x in links:
        item =  CrawlsiteItem()
        item["title"] = x.xpath('.//*[contains(@title, "View this job           description")]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
return items
```

and title returns an empty list.

I am capturing an xpath with an id tag in the links and then with in the links tag, I want to get list of all the values withthe title that has view this job description.

Please help me fix the error in the code.

Comment: Did you print the content of `x` to the console to see if it contains elements with the `title` you want to search for?

Comment: I have output this to csv file and in the file it return only the title as column header below which is empty.

Comment: I mean in your code where you can verify that the site Scrapy gets indeed contains the information you want. For example inside the `for` loop do `print x` to see what the contents of `x` are to see if you find the right elements or not.

Comment: The html has a table tag with id as mentioned some other attributes.Below that there is a tbody ,tr tags with in which I am trying to get the data .So, in   this case, I have got my output as                                                                      <selector xpath = ".//[@id = '']" data = u'<table cellpadding=  cell spacing= '0'  i'>

Comment: Consider this as part of html code that is available                                         <span class = "titlelink">
 <a id = "xyz" onclick= "abc" href="#" title = "View this job description">
 Associate
 </a>
</span>

Comment: is this code correct to get Associate as output.                                                          hs = Selector(response)
links = hs.xpath(".//span[@class = 'titlelink']/a/text()").extract()

Comment: item["title"] = hs.xpath("//span[@class = 'titlelink']//a").extract() gives me the html code that is <a href='#' .....></a> but when i add                   item["title"] = hs.xpath("//span[@class = 'titlelink']//a/text()").extract() it returns empty list. Please let me know how to get this text.

Comment: can you post the link and the name of the element that you want to extract

Comment: Link of the web page: https://cognizant.taleo.net/careersection/indapac_itbpo_ext_career/moresearch.ftl?lang=en           Elements I would like to get are the get the job title, requistion id, date posted and location. The above mentioned code is written under parse method to get the job title. Please let me know wha is the mistake I am doing here while trying to get the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you cURL the request of the URL you provided with `curl "https://cognizant.taleo.net/careersection/indapac_itbpo_ext_career/moresearch.ftl?lang=en"` you get back a site way different from the one you see in your browser. Your search results in the following `<a>` element which does not have any `text()` attribute to select:

```
<a id="requisitionListInterface.reqTitleLinkAction" 
    title="View this job description"
    href="#"
    onclick="javascript:setEvent(event);requisition_openRequisitionDescription('requisitionListInterface','actOpenRequisitionDescription',_ftl_api.lstVal('requisitionListInterface', 'requisitionListInterface.listRequisition', 'requisitionListInterface.ID5645', this),_ftl_api.intVal('requisitionListInterface', 'requisitionListInterface.ID5649', this));return ftlUtil_followLink(this);">
</a>
```

This is because the site loads the site loads the information displayed with an XHR request (you can look up this in Chrome for example) and then the site is updated dynamically with the returned information.

For the information you want to extract you should find this XHR request (it is not hard because this is the only one) and call it from your scraper. Then from the resulting dataset you can extract the required data -- you just have to create a parsing algorithm which goes through this pipe separated format and splits it up into job postings and then extracts the information you need like position, id, date and location.

Comment: I have couple of questions here:    1. How can we analyze whether a page have any ajax request, for future purpose. I have disabled javascript and still able to see the same page. 2. How to handle this using scrapy I am just started with scrapy.So any suggestions of links would help me.                Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to tell whether a site uses XHR requests or not programatically. The initial search should happen in a browser with good developer tools and you can guess the logic behind those requests. I use Chrome and if I disable JavaScript in the developer tools window I do not get the same site than with JS enabled -- I get the one Scrapy gets, without the search results.

Comment: I have used firepath/firebug and I used firefox for my scrapy work.I wil l try to check it again. If in the same case can you please let me know on how to work with scrapy to get the data we are intersted in in this case.Any tools etc which can help me to do the task.